# MSSQL get rows with timedifference below X

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff, self-join

I have a table with an `ID`, a `CHAR` and a `DATETIME` field. Now I want to get all rows, which are having a `DATEDIFF` of 5 minutes or less.

---

Sample data for reference:

```
  ID2    CHA       Timer
   1       B      2018-03-06 11:31:39
   2       S      2018-03-06 11:33:39
   3       B      2018-03-06 11:39:39
   4       S      2018-03-06 11:45:39
   5       B      2018-03-06 11:46:39
   6       S      2018-03-06 11:47:39
   7       B      2018-03-06 11:48:39
   8       S      2018-03-06 11:50:39
   9       B      2018-03-06 11:51:39
   10      S      2018-03-06 11:59:39
```

Desired output:

```
  ID2    CHA       Timer
   1       B      2018-03-06 11:31:39
   2       S      2018-03-06 11:33:39
   4       S      2018-03-06 11:45:39
   5       B      2018-03-06 11:46:39
   6       S      2018-03-06 11:47:39
   7       B      2018-03-06 11:48:39
   8       S      2018-03-06 11:50:39
   9       B      2018-03-06 11:51:39
```

My current query is this:

```
select *
from t t1
inner join t t2
on t1.ID = t2.ID
where datediff(minute, t1.timer, t2.timer)<=5
```

Sadly, this one returns the same entries multiple times. I think that this happens because of the `INNER JOIN`, but I can't tell for sure.

How do I get the desired result?

---

[Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f22b8/1) to test it for yourself.

Comment: it is because you are joining on same `id` .. so every record on to itself.. and it satisfies your `where` condition.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala how else should I perform a `SELF JOIN`? Or is there some better way to compare different rows in the same table?

Comment: Your SQL Fiddle data is slightly different than what you've posted above.  In the SQL Fiddle, row 4 is an 'S' row.

Comment: @WesH corrected it, but shouldn't make a difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Here is a new solution using the updated data.

```
SELECT  *
  FROM  t AS t1
  WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT  1
          FROM  t AS t2
          WHERE ( t1.timer <= DATEADD( MINUTE, 5, t2.timer )
                  OR t1.timer >= DATEADD( MINUTE, -5, t2.timer ))
                AND t1.id <> t2.id)
;
```

This returns any row with another row occurring within 5 minutes before or after it.  This should be able to use an index on the `timer` column if you're running this query with large volumes of data.

**OLD OUTDATED ANSWER**

You were very close.  You needed to join on the character field except when the ID matches.

```
select t2.*
from t t1
inner join t t2
on t1.cha = t2.cha
and t1.id <> t2.id
where datediff(minute, t1.timer, t2.timer) <=5
order by t2.id;
```

Comment: Can you explain why I should join on the CHAR?

Comment: you actually dont need, just add a "distinct" to avoid repeated rows. check my answer below

Comment: Your desired result implies that you want matching char values with a time difference of 5 minutes or less

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I think we need more than 4 rows of sample data.  Your SQL Fiddle data has two rows of each character, making multiple solutions capable of creating the desired result.

Comment: Added more data

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I've updated my answer to use the new data.

Comment: Why would you choose `DATEADD` over `DATEDIFF`?

Comment: That allows the t1.timer column to remain untouched by an expression, and therefore much more usable for indexing.  With few exceptions, wrapping a column in an expression prevents SQL Server from using an index on that column.

Comment: Ahh so its purely to be able to use an INDEX on that column. I doubt that there will ever be an INDEX on that column, so I will stick with DATEDIFF. Btw your answer helped me to get the right result!

Comment: In that case you can also use: abs(datediff(minute,t1.timer,t2.timer)) <=5

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LEAD` and `LAG` window functions:

```
select id, cha, timer
from (
  select id, cha, timer,   
         COALESCE(datediff(minute,                   
                           lag(timer) over (order by id),
                           timer) 
                  , 10) prev_diff,
         COALESCE(datediff(minute, 
                           timer, 
                           lead(timer) over (order by id))
                  , 10) next_diff
   from t) as x
where prev_diff <= 5 or next_diff <= 5
```

`LEAD` is used to get the `timer` value of the *next* record, whereas `LAG` is used to get the value of the *previous* record. If the difference between the current value and either of these two values is equal to or less than `5`, then you have a match.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/03b9d/24)

**Update:**

If `id` field cannot be used to determine row order, then you can use a number generated by `ROW_NUMBER` instead:

```
;with t_rn AS (
   select id, cha, timer,
          row_number() over (order by timer) as rn
   from t
)
select id, cha, timer
from (
   select id, cha, timer,   
          coalesce(datediff(minute,                   
                            lag(timer) over (order by rn),
                            timer) 
                   , 10) prev_diff,
          coalesce(datediff(minute, 
                            timer, 
                            lead(timer) over (order by rn))
                   , 10) next_diff
   from t_rn) as x
where  prev_diff <= 5 or next_diff <= 5
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e297b/2)

Thanks to @Vladimir, who could see the obvious where I couldn't, the above query can be simplified to:

```
select id, cha, timer
from (
   select id, cha, timer,   
          coalesce(datediff(minute,                   
                            lag(timer) over (order by timer),
                            timer) 
                   , 10) prev_diff,
          coalesce(datediff(minute, 
                            timer, 
                            lead(timer) over (order by timer))
                   , 10) next_diff
   from t_rn) as x
where  prev_diff <= 5 or next_diff <= 5
```

Comment: What would happen if the data weren't sorted? Meaning that in first and last row could be records that match, but between them are multiple records

Comment: @XtremeBaumer It works for the sample data provided after the edit. Can you add some more so that I can reproduce the issue?

Comment: Nvm it was my bad. Wondering how practical this solution is for multiple thousand rows

Comment: @XtremeBaumer You can test it and see how it compares to the other queries posted here. Place an index on `timer` before trying my query.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos, you don't need `row_number`. Just `order by timer` in `lag` and `lead` directly instead of `order by rn`.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Good catch! I've updated my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer, `LAG` and `LEAD` are much better than Cartesian product in my and other answers. `O(n)` vs `O(n*n)`.

Comment: Okay, how would I include other columns in the where clause? Like `cha != cha`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer If you want to exclude some records before calculating the time difference, then you can add any predicate you want in the `WHERE` clause of the inner query.

Comment: Yeah, but how exactly can I do what I just mentioned (`cha != cha`)? Or is that not an option with how the query is written?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can `CROSS JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

```
select *
from t t1
cross join t t2
where 
    ABS(datediff(minute, t1.timer, t2.timer))<=5
    AND t1.id < t2.id
```

This will give all possible pairs of rows with a time difference of less than 5 minutes.

`t1.id < t2.id` is needed to return only one instance of each pair.

If you are not interested in pairs as such, then, all you need is take each side of the pair and put them into one list. `UNION` will remove duplicates.

```
WITH
CTE_Pairs
AS
(
  select
    T1.id AS id1
    ,T1.cha AS cha1
    ,T1.timer AS timer1
    ,T2.id AS id2
    ,T2.cha AS cha2
    ,T2.timer AS timer2
  from t t1
  cross join t t2
  where 
      ABS(datediff(second, t1.timer, t2.timer)) <= 5*60
      AND t1.id < t2.id
)
SELECT 
  id1 AS id
  ,cha1 AS cha
  ,timer1 AS timer
FROM CTE_Pairs

UNION

SELECT 
  id2 AS id
  ,cha2 AS cha
  ,timer2 AS timer
FROM CTE_Pairs

ORDER BY id
;
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick

```
select distinct t1.*
from t t1
inner join t t2
on t1.ID <> t2.ID
where datediff(minute, t1.timer, t2.timer) between -5 and 5
```

Comment: i do still get the entry with ID 4 which shouldn't occur

Comment: change your where clause with `where datediff(minute, t1.time, t2.time) between -5 and 5`